# How to display this piece of information on a web app?

Tags: usability, website-design, user-expectation, info-visualisation

I'm in the middle of building some drafts for a future web platform for boardgame players. As I have a design question, I just discovered this web site, so this is the first time I post here.

I will be using Material Design but my question is unrelated. On the following screenshot, I display a list of search results (be tolerant: I'm not a designer, but a programmer, and I still need to design things by myself). My question is about the small part that shows a few meeples (the small gray characters). But before here is a bit of context:

The web site is about buying board games by sharing the costs. Once a boardgame is purchased, let's say by 4 people, it will be shared by them by using a booking system. This falls within the sharing economy.

So, that said, when a player starts the purchase process, he has to indicate how many members he wants in his circle for this game. In the first example, a guy wants exactly 3 partners. In the last one, 3 to 5 players are desired. The dark meeples show the number of members who have already chipped in.

Although I show you a draft, I think this is not an optimal way to present the information. Check, in the last example, I had to shrink the meeples... I don't know the theorical max number of partners yet. If this is, let's say, 8, it won't even fit in the rectangle area.

What I would like is:
- Show the desired number of partners
- Show the current involved partners
- Display the information so that it always takes the same real estate in the given fixed rectangle

Do you have some design ideas? Showing meeples was sure a nice visual in relation with the theme but it's maybe a bit too complicated. Keep in mind it should be easily feasible with html/css (no app yet), and be original ;)

Thank you

[image: draft]

Comment: May users see who (i.e., an avatar linked to the user’s profile) already committed to a game? What happens if the minimum number of partners is reached: does the original user decide if to wait (for optional partners) or if to purchase now? And if there are no optional spots, the purchase starts automatically?

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to keep the meeple icon, perhaps you can do something based on filling the icon, with a textual mention of the progress.

[image: Meeple example]

Comment: This is a nice idea, thank you, but one information is missing. If the number of desired partners is between 3 and 5, it is difficult to convey this range in the icon. Only the text could say 2 / 3 to 5 but this is a bit hard to read...

Comment: Ah, I must have misread the question. Perhaps you could set a bar in the meeple that displays the minimum number of partners, while the full meeple is the maximum number of partners. Then I'd display current, minimum and maximum in the text next to it.

Answer (score 0):

How about this - ;)
Possibly you could add a tool-tip to explain bit more when someone hovers over that area.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Amit. But I can't see the notion of members joining in these hands. I would like to see a progress. And like Lex's answer, the desired number of people can be a range...